# How to loop Options in EJS and not repeating 'selected' like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

How to loop Options in EJS and not repeating options every size is chosen?
if i add more size, the else if statement must be written again

```
<% if (size == "s") {%>

 <options value="s" selected>Small</options>
 <options value="m">Medium</options>
 <options value="l">Large</options>

<% } else if (size == "m") {%>

 <options value="s">Small</options>
 <options value="m" selected >Medium</options>
 <options value="l">Large</options>

<% } else if (size == "l") {%>

 <options value="s">Small</options>
 <options value="m">Medium</options>
 <options value="l" selected >Large</options>

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use tenary operator

more info here >> https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/

```
<options value="s" <%= size == "s" ? "selected" : ""; %>>Small</options>
<options value="m" <%= size == "m" ? "selected" : ""; %>>Medium</options>
<options value="l" <%= size == "l" ? "selected" : ""; %>>Large</options>
```